# Can I change binding_ip for mongod while mongodb is running?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a mongodb 2.2.2 setup on ubuntu 12.04 machine and I need to modify binding_ip list while database is running, without mongo restart. Is there a way to do so?
Is it possible to do from pymongo?

p.s. I've actually tried

mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 31.****

with bind_ip list supplied but it says

Wed Dec 19 17:02:05 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

and I'm not sure if it is not just restarting database.

Comment: Do you have root access on the machine? What exactly is the use case?

Comment: @kmkaplan Yes, I do have  root. Use case is pretty simple: some clients are constantly deployed on remote machines and connect to the db. I need to restrict access to db to those clients only.

Comment: Sounds as if adding `iptables(8)` rules could do the trick. Is that an option? My understanding is that your mongodb is currently answering on too many addresses and you want to limit those.

Comment: @kmkaplan I think it is. The only problem is I barely know iptables but it is fixable, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can do with `iptables(8)` rules. Then try (with 192.0.2.1 being the IP address you want to receive connections on):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d '!' 192.0.2.1 -p 27017 --m state --state NEW -j REJECT
```

If you already have iptables rules then you may need a different command. Check the output of `iptables -L INPUT`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and attention, will try it immediately.